# 2D Voxel isometric rendering with non grid-aligned objects

Tags: sprites, isometric, voxels, sdl2, draw-order

I'm currently working on making a simple SDL2 game (written in C++) where the maps are comprised of sprite voxels (essentially just a png of an isometric cube). Game entities move in 3D space. The world is rendered in 2D by a change of basis, where i,j,k are vectors (96,43,0), (96, -43, 0), (0, -105, 0)

Everything works fine with cubes that are aligned to the grid, the [x,y,z] locations and their contents are drawn in the correct order.
[image: Cubes render perfectly]

Moving entities are drawn at their closest grid-space location, resulting in a problem when the player sprite oversteps the boundary of their closet grid.

[image: Part of player outside grid boundary is 'chopped off']

I don't know how to overcome this problem. One idea I had was to assign the player a list of [x,y,z] locations they are occupying, and have each of those locations when drawn, draw only the segment of the sprite that occupies their region. Unfortunately I lack the knowledge of how that could be carried out using SDL2.

Any advice would be appreciated, even if it isn't SDL specific. I'm sure there's an obvious solution and well-known technique, but my searches so far haven't been successful.